# Edge Screen Capture API

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, screen-capture

The Windows 10 April 2018 Update has been released. One of Edge's new features is the Screen Capture API, but my environment is bad or abortError occurred and it did not work.
Has anyone worked with the Screen Capture API?
If it works, please tell me the source code.

By the way, the code I wrote is here. https://turbographics2000.github.io/screencapture_test/

```
btnScreenCapture.onclick = evt => {
    navigator.getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
        .then(stream => {
            // we have a stream, attach it to a feedback video element
            vid.srcObject = stream;
            vid.play();
        }, error => {
            console.log("Unable to acquire screen capture", error);
        });
 };
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us some written code.

Comment: I just checked your page and [it worked for me](https://monosnap.com/file/XlbYJDf5AZG9ZhWm5FSGZcmCZVSpnu.png). ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you for checking. As of now, there was a report that one person experiences the same error besides me. There was a report that the others succeed

Comment: I tried your example and it worked for me too. Are you sure you have latest Edge? (must be at least Edge/17.17134). In my case I struggled a bit to really get the update installed.